# How to specify vibrant appearance for secondary Today Centre widget text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I am working on my first Today Centre widget, which simply consists of three labels on the default storyboard. It's working fine, but I read in the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppExtensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH67-SW4) that secondary text should "use the system-provided vibrant appearance" with `notificationCenterVibrancyEffect`.

What's the correct way to add this vibrancy effect to my two secondary labels? I've read about `UIVisualEffectView`, but it's still not clear to me how to use it for this purpose. I don't think I want to put a blurred view behind my labels because Notification Centre already blurs the background.

Answer (score 2):

UIVisualEffectView when configured with a UIVibrancyEffect is meant to be used as a container—just drop your labels in its `contentView` and you’ll get the appropriate appearance on top of the Notification Center blur. The text color doesn’t matter; when it’s added to the `contentView` it gets special treatment and effectively always renders with the same appearance, though you can still adjust the alpha of the view (not of the text color) to make it more or less prominent.

[image: vibrancy examples]

Comment: Not necessarily—Interface Builder has support for visual effect views too. Just set them up following the same pattern. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27829073/30618) for some more detail on that.

Comment: OK, I think I finally got this worked out. I followed the answer you linked to in your comment, but additionally I had to tick the Vibrant checkbox in Interface Builder for both visual effect views. Crucially, I moved the primary label outside the view hierarchy of the two visual effect views, so it doesn't have a vibrant appearance. This leaves the secondary labels as part of the visual effect view hierarchy, which means they do get vibrancy.

Comment: Also, I still have no idea whether visual effect views in Interface Builder automatically use `notificationCenterVibrancyEffect`, or whether you have to build the whole lot in code to get that.

Comment: They probably don’t, but from my experimentation it would appear that `+notificationCenterVibrancyEffect` has the same appearance as a vibrancy effect configured for a dark-style blur, so you should be fine using that for now.

Comment: I wasn't happy with the appearance of my vibrant secondary text because it looked too dark, so I used one of my Apple Developer Technical Support incidents.

I was told that only a single visual effect view is needed and that it should have `notificationCenterVibrancyEffect` set via an IBOutlet. I pointed out that Interface Builder's _Visual Effects View with Blur and Vibrancy_ object uses a hierarchy of two visual effects views and was advised to file a bug report.

Comment: Interesting! Yep, definitely sounds like an issue worth filing. IB should be able to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

good day, first of all u should use a correct view hierarchy, when U add some objects in your VisualEffectView example:

[image]

UIVibrancyEffect used in combination with UIVisualEffectView, adjusts the colors of the content to make it feel more transparent. UIVibrancyEffect can blending some objects 
with the background example:

[image]

More particularly to your question(https://stackoverflow.com/a/25392645/4912496) Apple recommends to use vibrant effect for secondary text, because its simply beautiful for example(apple native app use vibrant effect, and Sports.ru don't use it):

[image]

But, some apps don't use this effect...
To ensure that your widget gets the vibrancy effect that’s appropriate for displaying items in the Today view, use notificationCenterVibrancyEffect.
Some info. https://www.omnigroup.com/developer/how-to-make-text-in-a-uivisualeffectview-readable-on-any-background